# packet of queries - MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, executereader

is there a way to send packet of queries in 1 query to mysql using c# ?
i mean i got 13 selects, they are not related, so cant union them, they get diffrent type of data. Now i got dbconn, 13x select, dbclose, its not a problem when it works over lan, but over internet it sometimes takes to slow cos of latency (13x select and recive data). Id like to make it with 1 query like:

select xxx from xxx;
select zzz from zzz;
select yyy from yyy;

and than read foreach table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send multiple statements and get multiple result sets using `MySqlDataReader`. You can do something like this:

```
var cmd = new MySqlCommand("...lot of SQL selects...");
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    // Go to a 'next result' each time.
    while (reader.NextResult())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // Read data from result set.
        }
    }
}
```

The trick is to use [`MySqlDataReader.NextResult`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqldatareader-nextresult) to skip to the next result set each time. Of course in your situation you know how many result sets you can expect so you shouldn't use a `while` loop but you get the idea.